# How to click on a href element by providing the link text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Here is the HTML source that i working on to automate using robotframework.

```
        <td width="150px" style="vertical-align: bottom; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;" >
           <a href="javaScript:{showValue('status_last_updated')}"><h2>System Status</h2></a>
        </td >
```

Table doesn't have a ID or name associated with it. All i have is the link text "System Status" which i could use as a reference to locate the element/run the java script.

Request to help me on this.

Comment: Here is the Keyword that i am using.
${Res}=            Click Link                  System Status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if xpath is allowed, then you can use

```
  //h2[contains(text(),'System Status')]
```

Comment: here http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html you can get how to click by using xpath

Comment: Done Accepted. Thanks for your Help.